# ng-repeat repeats too often

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Recently, I started to take a look into angular.js. I have managed to integrate it within a rails app now, but angular isn't working as it should.
This means, it repeats an object too often. Lets say, I have an Array with 2 JSONs and I want to repeat every single json.comment. When I have 2 jsons, I get every single comment twice, if I have 3 of them, I get every single comment three times. Here is the code:

```
var logbookApp = angular.module("logbookApp",[]);

logbookApp.controller("LogbookCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.entries = [
        {comment: "One"},
        {comment: "Two"},
        {comment: "Three"}
    ];
});
```

And here is the markup:

```
  <html ng-app="logbookApp">
  <body ng-controller="LogbookCtrl">
   <div class="view-container">
    <div ng-view class="view-frame"></div>

    <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="entry in entries">
           {{entry.comment}}
       </li>
    </ul>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: As far as I can see, there is nothing wrong with your code. Is it possible for you to set up a working, or non working (what ever you call it), version of your code on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/)?

Comment: Today I have no time to do so, but I will do it, tomorrow in the evening.

Comment: I've seen a similar problem caused by accidentally including the angular.js library in the page more than once. It's at least something quick to check as I agree this code looks fine.

Comment: @Marcel Gwerder I've put it on plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2BLSeEY8D8HHskFH3G1f?p=preview), but there is also no problem with this. Can it be, that this comes from rails?

Comment: @Andyroger Thanks for that hint. Somehow rails has included it also and now I have excluded the cdn (for the moment) and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this appears to have fixed the problem, I'll add as a full answer for the benefit of those stumbling across this question in future:

`ng-repeat` can create excess repeated items when the angular library is included more than once. From my brief testing I would expect there to be *n^a* items shown for *n* items expected in the repeat, and *a* versions of angular included in the page.

I would guess this is due to the first angular inclusion processing the `ng-repeat` directive on the initial element correctly. Subsequent inclusions then re-process the directive which is still present on each repeated item.

Comment: This can __also__ happen if you forget to remove the `ng-app` declarations from your html when you're manually bootstrapping your apps.

Comment: @James M. Lay I had this problem of ng-repeat repeating many times because I had ng-app declared in my div.  Your suggestion fixed my issue.  Stack Overflow should build a church at the spot where you uploaded your comment!

Comment: Haha, thank you! You leave these comments wondering if it's ever going to help someone, and 5 years later, it does!  Glad I could be of service :-)